# Assign a list to data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the next code I create a data.table and input some stuff:

```
library(data.table)
int.tables <- c( "Sheet_A","TBL 002"
                 ,"Sheet_B", "TBL 001"
                 ,"Sheet_B", "TBL 004"
                 ,"Sheet_C", "TBL 009")

int.tables<-data.table(matrix(int.tables,ncol = 2,byrow = T)) 
setnames(int.tables,c("sheet","table"))

level_Sheet_A <- list(   "Level_1",   "Level_2",   "Level_3" )

int.tables[sheet == "Sheet_B" & table %in% c("TBL 001", "TBL 004")
           , legend_levels := .(.(level_Sheet_A))]
```

However, in order to correctly input a list as a whole element per row requires the weird code `.(.())` in the last line. Otherwise, the output will enumerate the elements of `level_sheet_A` along the rows.
Is there a better/cleaner way to do it?

Comment: another option is `int.tables[sheet == "Sheet_B" & table %in% c("TBL 001", "TBL 004")
           , \`:=\`(legend_levels = .(level_Sheet_A))]`, but if you're looking for readability that deems like a downgrade

Comment: Since "recycling" doesn't work here, maybe just manually replicate to the desired length: `int.tables[, v := rep(list(level_Sheet_A), .N)]`. Of course, if you want readability, then your level list should be a character vector instead... `int.tables[, v := rep(list(as.character(level_Sheet_A)), .N)]`

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
int.tables <- data.frame(sheet = c( "Sheet_A", "Sheet_B", "Sheet_B","Sheet_C"),
                         table = c("TBL 002","TBL 001", "TBL 004", "TBL 009"))

index  <- int.tables$sheet == c("Sheet_B") & 
          int.tables$table %in% c("TBL 001", "TBL 004")

int.tables$legend_levels[index] <- list(c("Level_1", "Level_2", "Level_3" ))
```

Then you remove your dependency on `data.table` and avoid the unnecessary matrix construction. If you want to can add the class `data.table` to get the pretty printing at the end

```
class(int.tables) <- c("data.table", class(int.tables))
```